# Save iptables when iptables-save doesn't exist?

Tags: linux, wireless-router, iptables

I'm working on a [Soekris net4801](http://soekris.com/products/net4801.html) that is running an unknown distro of Linux. The kernel is 2.4.29, and iptables is v1.3.4.

I can't work out how to save the iptables. I searched the whole system for files/folders containing the name "iptables" and got 3 results:

```
/user/local/lib/iptables
/sbin/iptables
/lib/iptables
```

I've tried `iptables save`, `iptables-save` and `iptables save active`.

- "iptables save" and "iptables save active" give me an invalid argument error.
- "iptables-save" isn't a valid command.
- "iptables --help" gives me a list of valid switches, none of which have to do with saving.

Any ideas on how I can save the iptables?

Comment: iptables-save >/location/iptables.save    I don't know about 2011, but in 2016 this command works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you create a script ([like this](http://www.tty1.net/blog/2007-02-06-iptables-firewall_en.html)) that first clears all rules and then creates the rules.

These save commands were added later. I personally don't like them: you can't script.

Usually you add the script to the /etc/init.d dir. The script in the example is already an init-script. Then you have to add links to /etc/rcX.d. If you happen to have a debian-based distro the command update-rc.d will do that for you. Otherwise read [this](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/114107), it's the most distro-independent description I found.

Or google about rc.d and run levels.

Comment: Okay, so I'd need to create a script to re-write all the values currently in the tables?  How do I make sure that my additions are loaded on reboot?  All of the current entries seem to be static, but my additions disappear on reboot.

Comment: -> I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Simple type

iptables -L > iptables-save

Comment: And how do you restore the rules from that?

Answer (score -1):

Note that the command does require root or sudo.

Passing iptables-save will, like a number of privileged commands, produce unknown command error, occasionally also true for related man pages, and can be a point of confusion when entering a command to find it 'doesn't exist'.

Passing sudo iptables-save outputs to STDOUT as usual.

```
user@debian:~$ iptables-save
bash: iptables-save: command not found
```